# extract tuple and overwrite with int iteration

Tags: python, list

I have this list

```
list = [ [(6, 8, 9), 111], [(15,), 22], [(11, 20), 80] ]
```

and I want to extract the tuples and overwrite them with 0, 1, 2 ... so that I get:

```
new_list = [[0, 1, 2], [3], [4, 5]]
         # 6,8,9 was overwritten with 0, 1, 2
         # 15    was overwritten with         3 
         # 11,20 was overwritten with           4, 5
         # ...
```

I don't need the list[1] elements like 111, 22 and 80.

Is there an easy way to do this, I tried to loop through it but had problems with the right iteration.

Comment: Do you've `(15)` or `(15,)` in your real data?

Comment: Tip: `(15)` is not a tuple :) It is the `comma` that defines a tuple, not `()`

Comment: sorry. I have (15,). Corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> lis = [ [(6, 8, 9), 111], [(15, ), 22], [(11, 20), 80] ]
>>> c = count(0)
#If you want a list of list then use: [[next(c) for _ in x[0]] for x in lis] 
>>> [tuple(next(c) for _ in x[0]) for x in lis]
[(0, 1, 2), (3,), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: Btw, he asks for a list of lists, not a list of tuples :)

Comment: @SteinarLima Thanks, missed that. Updated the solution to include that.